# How to seed URLs as a text file in StormCrawler?

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

I have numerous URLs (about 40,000) that need to get crawled using StormCrawler.
Is there any way that I pass these URLs as a text file instead of a list in **crawler.flux**? Something like this:

```
spouts:
  - id: "spout"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.spout.MemorySpout"
    parallelism: 1
    constructorArgs:
      - "URLs.txt"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [FileSpout](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/spout/FileSpout.java) exactly for that purpose. It is used by the topologies mentioned by @sebastian-nagel and you can use them in yours just as well, see for example [this topology](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/stormcrawlerfight/blob/master/es-crawler.flux#L22).

Comment: getting this error using SolrSpout: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find a suitable constructor for class 'com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.util.StringTabScheme' with arguments '[DISCOVERED]'`

Comment: check that the constructor you are using matches your version of SC. See https://digitalpebble.blogspot.com/2019/01/whats-new-in-stormcrawler-113.html #664

Comment: Can you please update this branch and this file https://github.com/DigitalPebble/stormcrawlerfight/blob/solr/crawler.flux ? it seems outdated and does not work on my case! should I apply any modification on  **FileSpout.java** so this works? Thank you.

Comment: This branch is not maintained. It was needed for a one off comparison.

Answer (score 1):

For Solr and Elasticsearch there are injectors which read URLs from a file and add them as DISCOVERED items to the status index. Of course, it's required that Solr or Elasticsearch are used to hold the status index. The injector is launched as a topology, eg.

```
storm ... com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.ESSeedInjector .../seeds '*' -conf ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on **@Julien Nioche**'s answer, I wrote a **crawler.flux** that does what I wanted. This is the file:

```
name: "crawler"

includes:
    - resource: true
      file: "/crawler-default.yaml"
      override: false

    - resource: false
      file: "crawler-conf.yaml"
      override: true

    - resource: false
      file: "solr-conf.yaml"
      override: true



spouts:

  - id: "spout"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.solr.persistence.SolrSpout"
    parallelism: 1

  - id: "filespout"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.spout.FileSpout"
    parallelism: 1
    constructorArgs:
      - "."
      - "seeds"
      - true

bolts:
  - id: "partitioner"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.URLPartitionerBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "fetcher"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.FetcherBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "sitemap"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.SiteMapParserBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "parse"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.JSoupParserBolt"
    parallelism: 5
  - id: "index"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.solr.bolt.IndexerBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "status"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.solr.persistence.StatusUpdaterBolt"
    parallelism: 1

streams:
  - from: "spout"
    to: "partitioner"
    grouping:
      type: SHUFFLE

  - from: "partitioner"
    to: "fetcher"
    grouping:
      type: FIELDS
      args: ["key"]

  - from: "fetcher"
    to: "sitemap"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE

  - from: "sitemap"
    to: "parse"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE

  - from: "parse"
    to: "index"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE

  - from: "fetcher"
    to: "status"
    grouping:
      type: FIELDS
      args: ["url"]
      streamId: "status"

  - from: "sitemap"
    to: "status"
    grouping:
      type: FIELDS
      args: ["url"]
      streamId: "status"

  - from: "parse"
    to: "status"
    grouping:
      type: FIELDS
      args: ["url"]
      streamId: "status"

  - from: "index"
    to: "status"
    grouping:
      type: FIELDS
      args: ["url"]
      streamId: "status"


  - from: "filespout"
    to: "status"
    grouping:
      streamId: "status"
      type: CUSTOM
      customClass:
        className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.util.URLStreamGrouping"
        constructorArgs:
          - "byDomain"
```

Instead of **"."** you can set the directory that the URLs file is in there, and instead of **"seeds"** you can put your URLs file name.